# Label taking a really long time to change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning to develop an IOS app. I'm having the following problem. I want to use a label to display a string. It takes a really long time for this string to be displayed (10-15 sec). Is this normal? The following code is inside the viewDidLoad function

```
NSLog(self.example); //displays almost immediately 
_labelOutput.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.example;//takes 15 seconds
```

The entire viewDidLoad function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    double lat = 43.7000;
    double lon = -79.4000;
    NSArray *users = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_1",@"user_2",@"user_3", nil];

    id prediction = [[Prediction alloc] initWithUsers:users Lat:lat Lon:lon];

    [prediction populate:^{
        self.resName= [prediction generateRandom][@"id"];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.resName]);
        _labelOutput.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.resName];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Are you performing this on the main thread?

Comment: Are you sure the code is in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I checked and this is in viewDidLoad. I haven't really gotten into thread management or anything so I believe that I'm doing this in the main thread.

Comment: Show more of your `viewDidLoad` method so we can see some context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `-[Prediction populate:]` do with the block?  My guess is it runs the block on a background thread or queue.  You aren't allowed to modify the UI from a background thread or queue.  Your app might crash or just act unpredictably.  Your mysterious delay in updating the screen is a common symptom of this mistake.

You must only modify the UI from the main thread or queue.  Try this:

```
[prediction populate:^{
    self.resName= [prediction generateRandom][@"id"];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.resName]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _labelOutput.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.resName];
    });
}];
```

Comment: Prediction makes a few http requests to the server and runs the block code after completion. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @robmayoff What a great answer! I would have depressed by this issue. Thanks a lot man! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**ETA**: Rob's answer is probably spot-on...if you'd posted that code initially I would have caught it as well.

Try setting the label's text in viewWillAppear or perhaps viewDidAppear instead.

Setting the "text" property of a label will normally trigger a `[setNeedsDisplay]` call automatically via key-value observing, and this notifies the system that the label's view needs to be redrawn on the next run loop. However, `viewDidLoad` is called *before* your view is actually visible. It's likely that because of this, either `[setNeedsDisplay]` is not being called, or is being ignored because the label is not yet visible...and thus, you have to wait for some other event to trigger re-drawing of subviews.

You could test this theory by adding a `[self.labelOutput setNeedsDisplay]` call yourself in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize for not posting all of the code. I did not think it was relevant.

Comment: No worries! I wasn't offended, just wanted to point others to what I thought was the right answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3 you'll want to use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    _labelOutput.LabelName.text = "Something"
 })
```